# Codeigniter errors for model array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, models, controllers

This simple functionality driving me crazy - I'm trying to pull a row from database and pass it as array of information to my controller and same to my view - before passing this to view I need to get the slug field and redirect to `domain/quotes/this-is-test` to show correct information but I can't even do a basic query. Can you please help me with my lack of knowledge!

**Model**

```
  <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Quotes_model extends CI_Model{

  function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }

  function get_records(){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('quotes');

return $query->result();
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('quotes_model');
        $data['quote']= $this->quotes_model->get_records();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', array('data' => $data));

    }
}
```

and I have done this in my view :

**View**

```
    <?php die(var_dump($data)); ?>
```

**Error**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: models/quotes_model.php

Line Number: 16

array(1) { ["quote"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: you forgot to get data from model query result into `data` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$data['quote']= $this->quotes_model->get_records();
 $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```

and return your result from model:-

```
return $query->result();
```

or

```
return $query;
```

Comment: then need to check your query

Comment: this is my query now but still the same  function get_records(){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('quotes')
return $query->result();
}

Comment: may be your query not matching your conditions so try to refine your query

Comment: updated my model code above you can see its a basic query - I have also checked my table and fields names

Comment: try $query = $this->db->query("select * from quotes");

Comment: Amazing, well done - this is working now but how would I use my previous code to achieve this or is this a safe approach?

Comment: simply write your query in $this->db->query() and check you have all done right in join

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function get_records(){
$data = $this->db->select('*')
         ->from('quotes')
         ->join('authors', 'authors.id = quotes.author_id')
         ->join('genre', 'genre.id = quotes.id')
         ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
         ->limit(1)->row_array();
///$data = array();
return $data;


}
```

try ->row_array() if you want to fetch single row. If you want to fetch all records try result_array(). this will give you output in an array...

Comment: Try now please, its updated.. you didn't assign any result to data and you were returning it..

Answer (score 0):

you need to first pull your results through `result_array()`

Corrected Code:

```
function get_records(){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('quotes')
                        ->join('authors', 'authors.id = quotes.author_id')
                        ->join('genre', 'genre.id = quotes.id')
                        ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
                        ->limit(1);
    ///$data = array();
    if ($query->num_rows()) {
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: What about my controller? Ive changed my code to yours and I get a blank page with no source code

Comment: Hi, my code doesn't have an error. please check codeigniter user guide.

Answer (score 0):

your model has an error, you are returning `$data`, which is not defined!
add simply this:

```
return $query->result();
```

also change your controller:

```
$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```

and then you get your data in your view like this:

```
foreach ($quote as $row){
    $id=$row->author_id;
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: Ive changed it to that but I think there is an error somewhere as its not showing any result on home page

Comment: done it all, still a blank page - no errors but doesnt show anything

Comment: your order clause has an ambiguous id, change it to quotes.id. Try also without the joins, just to see if you get any output (you need to change your view to something lik $id=$row->quote.id

Comment: thats what i tried removed all so all im getting is select * from quotes

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake in function

```
 function get_records(){
$query = $this->db->select('*')
         ->from('quotes')
         ->join('authors', 'authors.id = quotes.author_id')
         ->join('genre', 'genre.id = quotes.id')
         ->order_by('id', 'RANDOM')
         ->limit(1);
///$data = array();
return $data;
```

}

you return $data; this should be return

```
$query->result();
```